# can be a NLP used case to get number in a proper format in python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nlp, data-cleaning, regex-group

I have an input -Dimension and I want my output in a specific form extracted from the text that I have in the dimension column.

I have used

```
df['output'] = df['Dimension'].str.extractall(r'(\d*\.?\d+)').astype(float).unstack().prod(axis=1) 
and
df['output'] = (df['Dimension'].str.extractall(r'(?<![+])(\d*\.?\d+)(?![%+])(?=\D|$)').astype(float).groupby(level=0).prod())
```

but i'm not able to print the desired output for any model. Please help me here in python.

| Model | Dimension | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4.31 m x 2 m x 3.222 m | 27.77364 |
| B | Bleach Regular 970ml | 970 |
| B | Bleach Regular 412m | 412 |
| B | Bleach Regular 97 gm | 97 |
| B | Bleach Regular 100gm | 100 |
| B | Det MAC 4in1 Disnfct Oud 900ml | 900 |
| C | Soap 175gm 3+1 | 175 |
| D | rangeZng 2x250m | 250 |
| E | R/B Cottn.Pad Rnd 80s SP6080NW | 0 |
| F | ProCln Kid.T/B Refill 2s | 0 |
| G | very good cream 250ml 2s 35% | 250 |
| H | vCand.l Musk 1Lt | 1000 |
| I | Candc Moist Musk 1L PO | 1000 |
| J | Medium 2+1 1's | 0 |
| K | Trsa T/B Frsh Hrd /Cap | 0 |
| H | .Lndn B/Spray(M) 4x50ml PO | 50 |
| L | O.Lndn B/Spray(M) 4x50 PO | 50 |
| L | Nice Soap Gardn.Blossm 170g 5+1 | 170 |
| L | Paste Astd 150ml 3s PO | 150 |
| x | Liquid 2lt | 2000 |
| y | Imp P.Nail StrngAlong30s PA015 | 0 |
| L | Lux Shwr 2X S.Rose250m+HW 245m | 245 |

tried regex function in the above and via excel I have tried `=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR((MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)*1),""))`
but wasn't accurate enough

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Asking for recommendations might not be appropriate on the Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but it might be possible to ask the question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Also, logging it on https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76949597